# PCB Headers for power and temperature sensors

Tags: pcb-design

Perhaps this is a little broad for stackexchange, in which case please just tell me in the comments, and I'll remove it forthwith.
I've done a lot of embedded development, and I have recently worked on a simple datalogger, somewhat specific to pharmacies. I have a prototype based on an ESP32 Firebeetle board, and some DS18B20 temp sensors.
I want to make a PCB, and it's a bit daunting. I have 3 specific questions, if anyone has a minute to help.

1. I will use a 5v barrel jack on the case for power. Should I use a PCB 2 pin header to allow for connection of this? Or just solder wires to the PCB. Looking at a low volume run, but it would be nice to be able to replace faulty PCBs easily.
2. Similarly, should I use a 3 pin PCB header per DS18B20? (I don't want to daisy chain them.) I am using 3.5mm mini jacks on the case to allow the DS18B20s to be plugged in externally.
3. I am using an RGB LED to indicate verious things. I was planning to mount this on the PCB, and bend it thru 90 degrees, so it can protrude from the case, in an LED mount. Is this lunacy?

Comment: One common thread for all of your questions: One can typically mount everything on the PCB, and design the enclosure around that.  Barrel connector: 90-degree on PCB through hole in your enclosure.  Sensor connector: 90-degree on PCB to through hole on your enclosure.  LED: 90-degree (or vertical) light-pipe over SMT LED on PCB to (you guessed it) a hole in the enclosure.  Save assembly time & avoid jumper wires to your enclosure walls.

Comment: Thank you - this is exactly the kind of information I was looking for. I'm totally unqualified for PCB design and layout, but I don't know whether the quantity of devices I will need ( < 200) will allow for the cost of getting a professional PCB design. Plus it really is a very simple circuit. I will look at 90 degree connectors, and LEDs, then see about getting an enclosure built to fit.

Comment: Often times you can just modify an enclosure yourself.  Although a quantity of 200 is annoyingly large enough where you may want to have a custom one made/modified for you (with spiffy graphics and labels).  For low-quantity assemblies, one can find an enclosure designed to hold a PCB, size your PCB to fit, and modify the enclosure to accept the needed connector/switch/LED holes.  Good luck!

Comment: I liked, and have learned from, each of the (currently) 2 answers below, as well as @ChrisKnudsen's comments. A quick google seems to suggest it's poor etiquette to accept more than 1 answer, so I have just up-voted each. Lack of familiarity with the rules - apologies.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not planning on disassembling the system frequently, wire to board connectors are an attractive option since they generally don't require special tools aside from perhaps a ferrule crimper and reduce the part count, labor, etc of crimping a plug, but they keep you from making a whole bunch of connectorized sensor or barrel jack subassemblies and just plugging them in at assembly time. If you're connecting individual wires to the WTB connectors there is the possibility of doing it wrong of course and in my experience it's a bit harder to catch then than having someone inspect subassemblies so tailor it to your existing or envisioned process is really what I'm saying.

1. If the current requirements are modest, say less than an amp (check your specific part datasheet) then 0.1" headers are certainly *doable* but they have no polarization, low vibration resistance, and the "official" crimper is shockingly expensive.  I suggest any number of wire to board connectors, either with screw or spring (recommended) terminals and ferrules or a detachable plug.
2. Same concerns for this connection, I suggest using a different connector entirely since otherwise the power cable *will* get plugged in to the temperature sensor socket and/or vice versa.
3. You can probably find appropriately sized standoffs to hold the LED leads in the proper angle/height and, importantly, keep them from touching. There are also light pipes which could be easier than trying to get a perfect bend every time.

Comment: Current reqs definitely < 1A, but I like the idea of spring WTBs, and ferrule-ended wires. Any thoughts on what other type I could use to prevent the wire from the barrel connector being plugged into the sensor WTB conns? This way I could get going with some off-the-shelf enclosures, custom-drilled.

Comment: You could, depending on your physical configuration, simply make it so the wires are too short to reach the wrong connector. There's also the strategy of putting a little heat shrink label on each wire and matching it to a screen printed label on the board. It also helps to have either a physical sample or a detailed picture of a properly wired system so the assembler can reference it.

Answer (score 1):

1. PCB mounted connector will get rid of the problem, the connector will move with the PCB. Otherwise it's just a cost vs serviceability tradeoff decision
2. Same situation with the 3.5 mm TRS connectors.
3. Using a right-angle surface mount LED and a panel-mount light guide / diffuser on the enclosure will allow disassembly similar to previous items. Surface mount LEDs are cheaper to be placed on automated assembly line. Installing a through-hole led includes manual labor and more possibilities of assembly failures.

Comment: Yep, seems like PCB-mounted connectors , sockets, LED are a popular choice. I need to go talk to some PCB making people, and look into cost of custom enclosures.

Comment: Yeah, the enclosures might have a steep startup cost. I've found custom sheet metal enclosures to be at a good price point. 3D-printing is of course cheap, if you can accept those. One more option is to get an enclosure with end panels and just order custom end panels.